# Write to s3 from blocking queue java using camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a use case where I want to write in memory Java blocking queue contents using apache camel route to S3. Is this even possible??

The workaround I can think of is to pull records from blocking queue and flush to local file and then to S3 via file-s3 route.

Update:

Route :

```
    fromF("seda:awsquue?concurrentConsumers=3&queue=#NonLimitQueue%s", getSourceId())
    .convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
    .setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_LENGTH, simple("${in.header.CamelFileLength}"))
    .setHeader(S3Constants.KEY,simple("${in.header.CamelFileNameOnly}"))
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "route started")
    .to("aws-s3://" +"bucket"
    + "?amazonS3Client=#s3ClientProfiler&serverSideEncryption=AES256&multiPartUpload=true");
```

Queue creation in different workflow :

```
        context.registerBean("NonLimitQueue"+sourceId,ArrayBlockingQueue.class, () -> queue);
```

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new S3RouteBuilder(sourceId));
            queue.add("qqqq");
```

When route starts it fails with exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.apache.camel.Exchange (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.camel.Exchange is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:171)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

which I believe is failing at queue.add("qqqq"). How to write to queue explicitly is not clear to me.

Comment: Are you trying to read from S3 or write to S3?

Comment: I need to read from queue and write to S3. Camel SEDA is gives out of box blocking queue but I am not able to produce custom messages to it.

Comment: The way S3 writing works is by writing the body of the message as the file contents into S3. So what you apparently want  is to send to SEDA messages with the file contents in the body. SEDA endpoints themselves are no different from Direct endpoints; you can send messages to them in the exact same way.

Comment: To tell you exactly what to do, you have to update your question with proper code samples.

Comment: Updated the question @jwwallin

Answer (score 0):

camel seda is a  blocking queue for apache camel. default queue size is 1000 .you can increase or decrease this size.

```
    from("aws-s3://helloBucket?accessKey=yourAccessKey&secretKey=yourSecretKey")
.to("seda:awsquue");

from("seda:awsquue?concurrentConsumers=3&queue=#NonLimitQueue").
// do  something 



// for quarkus it is 

@ApplicationScoped
public class ConnectionConf {

    @Named("NonLimitQueue")
    @Produces
    public BlockingQueue arrayDeque(){
        return new ArrayBlockingQueue(30000);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for insight. How can we produce String or custom object to "NonLimitQueue". I see (github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-seda/src/…) consumes Exchange object only.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is Camel trying to read "qqqq" as an Exchange... Camel routes can only handle Exchange-objects and not arbitrary data-structures. What you should do is place the stream you wish to use in the body of an Exchange and send that exchange to the queue.

Something to the effect of this:

```java
    camelContext.addRoutes(new S3RouteBuilder(sourceId));
    Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(camelContext);
    exchange.getIn().setBody("qqqq");
    queue.add(exchange);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer :)